# assign different button names to id using for loop

Tags: android, button

I have an 5 `buttons` and I need to explicitly create each `editText`. I found a solution by using for loop we can group the buttons. like below.

```
private Button[] btn = new Button[4];
private int[] btn_id = {R.id.btn0, R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3}; 
 for(int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
        btn[i] = (Button) findViewById(btn_id[i]);
        btn[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(207, 207, 207));
        btn[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Here I need to use the same `button` only. How can I use the above code for the different `button` names?

```
 private Button btn1,button2,bt3,b4;
```

How can I achieve the for loop for the above `button` declaration. I tried to add the all the `button` in to an `arrayList` bu that doesn't work. Any suggestions.

Comment: So is it about Buttons or about EditText?

Comment: @Xenolion - buttons

Comment: Do you realneed a for loop or you just want a simplification not to repeat the same thing!

Comment: I think only one method is enough to avoid repetition that a for loop!

Comment: Append created buttons with the name in "btn" and loop through it.

Comment: I need to use the for loop but i dont want to use the same name append with numbers instead different names.

Comment: Does you buttons id look like `R.id.btn0,R.id.btn1,R.id.btn2`? Or completelydifferent?

Comment: the button ids are look like above mentioned.

Comment: You can find all buttons different  click listener right?@user2269164

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, Hope this help you!

```
for(int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){      
     int btnId= mContxt.getResources().getIdentifier("btn_"+i, "id", getPackageName());
     Button btn = (Button)findViewById(buttonId);
     btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(207, 207, 207));
     btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: @Mohammed - Id is not a problem. How can use different button names inside the loop.

Comment: You can generate array of the button dynamically and then assign the id to the same.

Answer (score 0):

After the `for-loop` you have this `array` filled with `Buttons`,

```
private Button[] btn = new Button[4];
```

Then you can just do this, after the `for-loop`

```
private Button btn1 = btn[0];
private Button btn2 = btn[1];
private Button btn3 = btn[2];
private Button btn4 = btn[3];
```

You can do this in a better way, but I hope this will give you a small indication on how to do it.